# PostgreSQL Regexp - Find records with single char

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to get from table all records, that have in column **only one** `-`.

```
select ta.name, ta.created from tol.order ta 
where ta.name similar to '%-{1}%' and ta.created > '2018-05-01'
```

But have no success.

For instance I should get all records with name like:

```
'test-testtest'
```

but NOT like

```
'test-test-test'
```

Thanks for any advise and help.

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Let me know is that worked for you or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **non-regex** way with PostgreSQL's built in function. See [Array Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html)

```
SELECT ta.name, ta.created from tol.order ta 
WHERE (array_length(string_to_array(ta.name, '-'),1)-1) = 1 
    and ta.created > '2018-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sth like:

```
SELECT ta.name, ta.created from tol.order ta WHERE ta.name ~ $rxb$^[^-]*?-[^-]*$$rxb$ and ta.created > '2018-05-01';
```

Comment: not selects orders with name like 'test-testtest', just selects nothing

Answer (score 0):

I would take the opposite approach and do a regex to **exclude** anything that had:

a hyphen: `-`
followed by any characters (including none): `.*`
followed by another hyphen: `-`

```
select ta.name, ta.created
from tol.order ta 
where ta.name !~ '-.*-' and ta.created > '2018-05-01
```